# How to get the slopes of different sets of data in excel, using the offset function?

Tags: excel

I have a dataset structured such that the x-values representing year number goes from 1 to 18, but the dataset contains over 500 instances of the years going from 1 to 18 with different y-values for each instance.

```
x_values    y_values
1             0.10
2             0.20
3             0.25
.             .
.             .
.             .
18            16.7
1             0.13
2             0.18
3             0.22
.             .
.             .
.             .
18            17.1
```

where this pattern repeats over 500 times.

I would like to calculate the slopes for each of the instances, using the slope function.

In a previous scenario, I wanted to find the average y-value for each instance, and I used the formula:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($B$2,(ROW()-ROW($C$2))*18,,18,))
```

Where $B$2 was my reference cell indicating the first y-value in the first instance.

I would like to apply a similar formula to calculate the slopes, but so far I'm getting a #N/A error when I use this formula:

```
=SLOPE(OFFSET($B$2,(ROW()-ROW($D$2))*18,,18,),$A$2:$A$19)
```

where the range $A$2:$A$19 represents the 18 x-values.

Any help on why this error occurred and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you step through this formula with Evaluate Formula, you will see that there are curly brackets round the row numbers - so the Row functions are delivering a single-element array. You can make them into scalars by using Index:

```
=SLOPE(OFFSET($B$2,INDEX((ROW()-ROW($D$2))*18,1),0,18,1),$A$2:$A$19)
```

**Note 1:**

Better to use Index and avoid using volatile functions like Offset:

```
=SLOPE(INDEX(B:B,(ROW()-ROW($B$2))*18+2):INDEX(B:B,(ROW()-ROW($B$2))*18+19),$A$2:$A$19)
```

**Note 2:**

I can't fully explain why you get this behaviour with Slope but Average is OK. It seems that Average can handle an array of arrays like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(AVERAGE(OFFSET(A2,{1,2},0,1,1)))
```

while Slope can't, but it still doesn't entirely explain what you see when you step through the formula.